# How do I create a UserControl<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, xaml, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it Possible to Make a Generic Control in .Net 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395321/is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-control-in-net-3-5)

How do I create a `UserControl<T>` in C# in Winforms or Webforms?

```
public partial class MyView<T> : UserControl
 { 
        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        } 
 }
```

When I try this, I get the following error message:

```
The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
```

Is it not possible to make a UserControl generic in .NET 3.5?

Comment: Is this a WinForms user control? The form designer can't handle generic forms or user controls; it will give you an error when you try to open `MyView`.

Comment: its a WPF UserControl! sorry forgot about that.

Comment: You just added all the tags except for WPF? What does asp.net and winforms has to do with it? What were you thinking George?

Comment: @Arcturus I made the edit at 12:56UTC, she responded in a comment at 12:59 UTC that it was WPF. The reason I didn't put the WPF tag is because at the time she hadn't speficially said it was WPF, and from the code it could have been Winforms or Webforms development. That's "What I was thinking."

Comment: @George Yes, but it was neither. Did the InitializeComponent method not ring a bell?

Comment: @Arcturus both Winforms and Webforms utilize `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: You are correct, it does indeed. But why instead of asking Lisa, did you edit the question and put both Winforms and Webforms in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no!

The Xaml just cannot handle it in .NET 3.5. You can however derive of generic classes, so

```
public partial class MyView : MyView<T>
```

But you will need to specify it in the Xaml as well with the [TypeArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx)

```
<my:BusinessObject x:TypeArguments="x:String"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial class split across several files. Open the `MyView.Designer.cs` file and make it generic there too.