# Could not find type... Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, generics, user-controls

I created a Generic User Control with following signature..

```
public partial class GridMastercontrol<TMainEntity, TChildEntity> : UserControl
where TMainEntity : class
where TChildEntity : class
{
// more code here
}
```

A reference is created as follows-

```
GridMastercontrol<STACS.ACASupp,STACS.ACALot> ctrl=
                 new GridMastercontrol<STACS.ACASupp,STACS.ACALot>();
```

The control works perfectly on run-time. But, when i open the designer the design is not displayed and the following two warnings popup-

Warning 1-
Could not find type 'WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.GridMastercontrol'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

Warning 2- 
The variable 'ctlMasterACA' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

It was working perfectly in design mode when i did not implement the generics concept into it. but now, it does not. :(

Please help me..
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked if the generics were implemented in all files?? That's a partial class, so it's declared in more than one file.

Comment: And see if this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395321/is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-control-in-net-3-5?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

An answer to very this question you may find at:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c774bc84-87cb-4464-adb2-5f1391ed2389/could-not-find-type-please-make-sure-that-the-assembly-that-contains-this-type-is-referenced

regards,
Hlina